Do images have propositional content?
It's uncontroversial that most declarative sentences have propositional content, and can therefore be true or false. However they are just one way of conveying information. If 'There exists a red wall' has propositional content, does an image of a red wall not share the same propositional content? Both are a representation of the information that there are existent red walls, so why don't we talk about true and false images the same way we talk about true and false statements?

If "there exists a red wall" and "an image of the red wall" share the same propositional content, they could be expressed in the same way, namely "there exists a red wall". So true and false images translate into true and false representations of the image in language. And we don't talk about images, only the content of them, which is also expressed in language. If this is way off target, could you clarify your question?

The Picture Theory of Language was briefly put forth by early Wittgenstein (SEP). From WP:

The picture theory of language, also known as the picture theory of meaning, is a theory of linguistic reference and meaning articulated by Ludwig Wittgenstein in the Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus. Wittgenstein suggested that a meaningful proposition pictured a state of affairs or atomic fact. Wittgenstein compared the concept of logical pictures (German: Bilder) with spatial pictures. The picture theory of language is considered a correspondence theory of truth.

In fact, from a translation of Tractatus:

2.2 The picture has the logical (logico-pictorial) form of representation in common with what it pictures (depicts).

Here, the primary mode of thought is considered visual, a development that does capture the dominance of our visual systems in our cognition (brainline.org). Thus, it is not far-fetched to try to characterize our language as a tool for describing what we see and think.
But just like the Language of Thought Hypothesis (SEP) has some challenges that are difficult to overcome, characterizing truth as a set of pictures also has troubles. For instance, pictures are notoriously information rich, but that comes at the price of being ambiguous. Certainly natural language has ambiguity (and vagueness), but given the Principle of Compositionality, it is much easier to see how complex meanings are built from simpler pieces. In this way pictures might be too rich. Also, one cannot have a conversation with pictures in the way one can have with words. Lastly, certain thoughts are difficult to express with language, let alone pictures. Would it even be possible to communicate quantum mechanics entirely in pictures?
You ask:

Do images have propositional content?

So, the answer is yes, and undeniably so since some early writing systems and modern societies still use pictograms. Pictograms, therefore, can be semiotic in the same way as other signs, but images as signs are far more difficult to use to convey meanings because in a very real way, they do not abstract enough to reduce the vagueness and ambiguity. Thus, the move towards abstracting pictograms to logographs, syllabaries, and alphabets. (Modern Japanese serves as a great example using with kanji, kana, and romaji, concurrently.)

For a deeper analysis of communication, consider relevance theory and it's notion of ostention and inference being necessary for communication, and the impact of using images as acts of ostention.

@andrós The second quote claims that linguistic pictures (captured by propositions) and literal pictures are somehow equivalent. Thus, the word 'picture' in that quote is used distinctly with both the metaphor and literal definition obviating your request.


It's uncontroversial that most declarative sentences have propositional content,

Not so fast. While outside the philosophic context hardly anyone would object, in philosophy of language a lot more precision about definitions is required.
In general sentences, or more precisely symbols, do not have any meaning intrinsically. Rather, we actively assign meaning to them when reading them (based on rules or conventions as an example, though the details are complex). We might do so differently for the same symbol/sentences depending on context. This is not objective unless we use an objective mapping from symbols to meaning, like maths (or a dictionary, where things get more fuzzy).
The same goes for images that do not contain any explicit encoding of text. We can assign meaning to images and such meaning can be in the form of proposition. But without any formalization, that meaning remains subjective. Formalization of images could be seen in traffic signs and shapes, like the lines between lanes of a road. They are interpreted to mean something, without being "symbols" in a traditional sense. Similarly we can consider motions and gestures, like body language. Or you might think of many creative variations for indicating male and female toilets.
But other examples of non-formalized expression of "something" are expressionist paintings, conveying some emotion or feeling maybe, but very subjectively.
Music (without lyrics) is also similar to such expressionist content, also dance, fashion, sculpturing, even cooking. To illustrate, people can express a gender with their hairstyle and clothing which can be "true" in the sense of being the gender with which they identify, or "false" if they cannot identify with that gender. So if two people look a t a photo, one might say: "This is a girl on a chair, while the other might say this is a girl dressed up as a boy sitting on a chair" (depending on whether they know the person in the photo an dhow they identify their gender. I am using a binary example just for simplicity, not excluding NB).

Do images have propositional content?

In that sense, I would say: No less than sentences, but if we agree that sentences have no content (but instead get assigned content at the time of interpretation), the same goes for images. So it depends a bit on definitions.

why don't we talk about true and false images the same way we talk about true and false statements?

So far, in philosophy nobody found sufficient benefit to reason with informally represented meanings.
But there are images of which we talk about truth and false:

Currently in the context of fake news, faked photos are talked about a lot
In the context of straightedge and compass geometry in maths propositions can be expressed (some geometry can be used for proof in drawing). There is also a formal language behind geometry, but as an example it can be shown with careful drawing that the heights in a triangle intersect in a single point known as the orthocenter. So such an image does not merely express a statement, but it also demonstrates it
Diagrams like blueprints in architecture can be true about the current state of a building


+1 "In that sense, I would say: No less than sentences, but if we agree that sentences have no content (but instead get assigned content at the time of interpretation), the same goes for images." And indeed, sentences are ultimately composed of graphemes which are undeniably pictures themselves!

You could improve this answer by mentioning the role that rules or conventions play in assigning meaning. As written it seems to imply that meaning is assigned by arbitrary stipulation. Also, you seem to be conflating "expressing a meaning" with "presenting an impression". It is easy to come up with sentences that have a true meaning but are intended to give a false impression and vice versa, and the impression is often not reducible to a proposition.

@DavidGudeman, i tried to improve. If it's a matter of switching out words in a sentence, feel free to improve.

@JD yes, though language sentences can also exist in non-written form like digital or neural correlate, the grapheme writing is just a practical matter.

Verbal utterances (speech), ink marks on paper (words or drawings), pictures, sensory perceptions, memory traces that suddenly interrupt an ongoing process -- any of those, and in fact any observed thing or event,  can convey information to an organism (or mechanism) that is able to interpret them and convert them into something that is meaningful to it.

Interpretation subsumes all internal processes that couple observations (information) to actions (meaning). The number of independent things a device [e.g. an organism, a mechanical input-output device] could observe can be considered a measure of its uncertainty (entropy of observation). The number of independent actions in its repertoire of response can be considered a measure of its indecision (entropy of action).

[Davig Haig, Making Sense. Also in David Haig, From Darwin to Derrida, 2020]
A verbal assertion is just an object (a series of ink marks) or an event (a sequences of sound waves). A picture is also just an object. As such, as things in themselves (as it were), they do not "carry" or "contain" any information (as if they were little train cars with some hidden semantic cargo). These objects or events may become informative to an interpreter when interpreted by that interpreter. Being informative and being meaningful is always subjective rather than objective; or rather, it is always relational, relative to an interpreter input-output device, it's not a property of the inputs or outputs considered in isolation from those devices. (It can be "objective" in the sense that multiple interpreters may react in the same way to certain repeated observationsA.)
The utterance "There is a red wall in front of you" (an assertion) may have as much (or as little) information to 'you' as "Watch out! Red wall in front!" (exclamation, noun phrase, where's the proposition?). Neither is very informative to me, if I already saw that red wall. If I ask you, in advance, what I will see when I get to point X -- which I never visited before -- and you silently show me a picture of a red wall, then that picture may -- in the given context of our actions and predictable observations -- convey the same information as you uttering "A red wall".
Both verbal utterances or graphical (or photographic) depictions may be "false" or misleading when they trigger "mistaken" meanings. They can do so because, in context, another interpreter device intended to trigger this (deceit or art), or because of some malfunction in the interpreter, or because of an unanticipated input -- there may be various causes at various levels of the process. What we're mostly concerned about, of course, is intentional misinformation, deceit and manipulation. (But sometimes we're also concerned about getting too much information, or not getting the right kind of information. It's funny that philosophers hardly seem to pay attention to this.)
When Pope Innocent X saw Velazquez' portrait of him, he is rumored to have exclaimed "È troppo vero! È troppo vero!" ("It's too true! It's too true!"). The portrait shows him as a highly intelligent, but shrewd, old man. Francis Bacon drew out these meanings (suspicious, shrewd, threatening) a little further in his Study after Velazquez. If we take this usage of "true" seriously, then "truth" seems to admit of infinitely many degrees, from "totally false" to "false", "somewhat misleading", "overall true, but colored by bias", from "true", to "too true, too true", to "horrifyingly true" -- and everything in between.
When talking about "propositions" philosophers and logicians try to pin the world down to either True and False, just those two, clearly separated logical states. "The world is everything that is the case". But this is a huge simplification of the way the concept of truth -- with it's various shades of meaning and it's degrees of satifiability -- is used both in everyday life and in science.
If propositions are defined as assertions (linguistic objects that have the form of assertions, that are used as assertions), then (again) their "propositional content" can only be whatever meaning an interpreter assigns to them. An observed picture (graphical or photographic image) can have just as much "content", but will usually have much more content, and it may be used to tell multiple, very different "stories". Even an unmanipulated photograph is a particular, framed snapshot in time that is usually embedded in a larger communication (including verbal messages), so it may be "true" or "false" (or anything in between) depending on the larger framing (and one's interpretation). One example are the photos of the toppling of the statue of Sadam Hussein in Firdos Square (e.g. NYT The Toppling, which has been called "the most staged photo opportunity since Iwo Jima" (quoted in wiki) and which can be "read" either as showing popular exultation about being liberated or as US propaganda justifying the invasion (or as both, really). Another example could be the photographs and movies of Leni Reifenstahl.
Susan Sontag's On Photography is a "philosophical" (socio-historical/culture-critical) essay about the role and impact of photography in our society. She argues that photography has led to a "chronic voyeuristic relation to the world". It may be interesting to contemplate what "true" or "false" would mean in this respect. The essay ends with the following paragraph:

The powers of photography have in effect de-Platonized our understanding of reality, making it less and less plausible to reflect upon our experience according to the distinction between images and things, between copies and originals. It suited Plato's derogatory attitude toward images to liken them to shadows -- transitory, minimally informative, immaterial, impotent co-presences of the real things which cast them. But the force of photographic images comes from their being material realities in their own right, richly informative deposits left in the wake of whatever emitted them, potent means for turning the tables on reality -- for turning it into a shadow. Images are more real than anyone could have supposed. (...) If there can be a better way for the real world to include the one of images, it will require an ecology not only of real things but of images as well.


A.
The contrast between "subjective" and "objective" can be quite misleading.
What we care about in "objectivity" is repeatability/invariability of observations across time and across different observers.

(Stelling VII) Het toekennen van "objectiviteit" aan physische grootheden als massa en aantal berust op de invariabiliteit daarvan bij een belangrijke groep van verschijnselen in het wiskundig natuurbeeld.


(Thesis VII) Attributing "objectivity" to physical quantities like mass and (cardinal) number is based on their invariability in an important group of phenomena in the mathematical representation of nature.

[L.E.J. Brouwer, Over the Grondslagen van de Wiskunde (On the Foundations of Mathematics), PhD thesis, 1907]
